# Database Design for Search Engine?

Tags: database-design, web-crawler, search-engine, database-schema

I have Created a app that crawl the website. [here -
 http://crawler.javaignite.com/](http://crawler.javaignite.com/)

I got all relative URL and having its meta keyword and description including title.

But now i want to store these data in some tables & i don't have idea about how search engine store data and search so help me create basic schema for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to create but need more improvement on this . basically i use only three tables

**table : website_mst**

```
website_id
website_url [root]
website_visitperiod  // no of days to revisit
```

---

**table: crawled_history**

contains multiple data as how many times it crawled

```
crawled_id PK 
website_id FK [ref. website_mst]
crawled_url
crawled_datetime
```

---

**table: crawled_page**
contains only meta and description

```
crawled_id  FK [ref. crawled_history]
meta_title
meta_keyword
meta_description
total_viewed
updated_on
```